# Application Failed Codesign

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm pulling my hair out over this and still can't find what's wrong. Basically, I have an app that I'm ready to launch but whenever I archive and build I keep getting an "Application Failed Codesign" warning.

This is the code signing:

[image: Screenshot of code signing]

This is the warning I get:
[image: Screenshot of warning]

And this is my keychain, all certificates are active:
[image: Keychain screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the release configuration is signed with a distribution certificate not a development certificate.

Comment: @Abizerm do you known if the pp should be ad hoc or app store?

Comment: Both ad-hoc and app store require distribution certificates.

Comment: What do you mean both and at the moment I have certificates in ad hoc and that's it do you think that could be the problem .. @Abizern

Comment: I mean for ad-hoc builds and app store builds you need to use a distribution certificate.

Comment: I still haven't fix my warning I think I need the any ios SDK bit should be something different please help